# What kind of encoding is this?

Tags: c#, encoding

What kind of encoding do you use to encode http:// as http%253A%252F%252F

HttpUtility.UrlEncode gives http%3a%2f%2f

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you're looking at is text that has been passed through UrlEncode *twice*.

The second time changes the `%` symbols to `%25`.

It's unusual to pass an *entire* URL through UrlEncode anyway, unless you are passing it as a parameter in another URL (for redirection, for instance).

Comment: yeah.. i just found that out too :)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like `UrlEncode` was called twice, encoding the literal `%` as `%25` (which is the correct result, by the way).